# Dynamic path routing with angular

Tags: angular

im new to angular ... i try to build new angular project with dynamic urls ..... mydomain name is `xxx.yyy.com` after this url i give dynamic name like `xxx.yyy.com/name1`, `xxx.yyy.com/name2`,`xxx.yyy.com/name3` etc.,

if i give this `xxx.yyy.com/name1` url in browser means it gets all my data...i used homecomponent for this like..`{ path: '',  component: HomeComponent, children: [ { path: '**', component: HomeComponent} ]}` ....if i want to search any product means this urls should come with `xxx.yyy.com/name1/search/` i created seperate component for search like product-list component ... i try this path for routing

```
{ path:':string/search',component:ProductListComponent}
```

it not goes to productlist page ... it shows home page only

i tried this url navigation to go for serach page from home page

```
`this.router.navigate([name1+'/search'])`..
```

i get first segment for name1 and redirect to search using onclick method...how to go to productlist component page with dynamic url which i want.. thanks in advance...!

Comment: Show your actual router file, not just parts of it (as order matters in routing)

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
  
  { path: '',  component: HomeComponent, children: [ { path: '**', component: HomeComponent} ]},
  { path:':string/search',component:ProductListComponent,children: [ { path: '**', component: HomeComponent} ]}
 ];

Comment: Why the children again in your last route..? That one goes to the home component..?

Comment: i removed this children but it does not goes to productlist again in home page only

Comment: @MikeOne is this correct path:':string/search' for dynamic url

Comment: Yes, that should work (although I shouldn’t use string as this is a reserved word in javascript)..

Comment: but it is not working for me.. there is anyother way to get solution...